# How to calculate the mean and standard deviation of multiple dataframes at one go?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've several hundreds of pandas dataframes and And the number of rows are not exactly the same in all the dataframes like some have 600 but other have 540 only.

So what i want to do is like, i have two samples of exactly the same numbers of dataframes and i want to read all the dataframes(around 2000) from both the samples. So that's how thee data looks like and i can read the files like this:

```
5113.440  1     0.25846     0.10166    27.96867     0.94852    -0.25846   268.29305     5113.434129
5074.760  3     0.68155     0.16566   120.18771     3.02654    -0.68155   101.02457     5074.745627
5083.340  2     0.74771     0.13267   105.59355     2.15700    -0.74771   157.52406     5083.337081
5088.150  1     0.28689     0.12986    39.65747     2.43339    -0.28689   164.40787     5088.141849
5090.780  1     0.61464     0.14479    94.72901     2.78712    -0.61464   132.25865     5090.773443

#first Sample
path_to_files = '/home/Desktop/computed_2d_blaze/'
lst = []
for filen in [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files) if '.ares' in x]:
   df = pd.read_table(path_to_files+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')
   df = df.sort_values('stlines', ascending=False)
   df = df.drop_duplicates('wave')
   df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
   lst.append(df)


#second sample

path_to_files1 = '/home/Desktop/computed_1d/'
lst1 = []
for filen in [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files1) if '.ares' in x]:
   df1 = pd.read_table(path_to_files1+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')
   df1 = df1.sort_values('stlines', ascending=False)
   df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('wave')
   df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
   lst1.append(df1)
```

Now the data is stored in lists and as the number of rows in all the dataframes are not same so i cant subtract them directly.

So how can i subtract them correctly?? And after that i want to take average(mean) of the residual to make a dataframe?

Comment: You could just slice the first item off each.

Comment: i don't want to do that because in the original data i've more or less 800 rows and there lots of outliers in it so it's not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `apply`. Just use Boolean making:

```
mask = df['waves'].between(lower_outlier, upper_outlier)
df[mask].plot(x='waves', y='stlines')
```

Comment: Much better solution! I was not aware of the `.between` function.

Comment: The problem is that "wave" and "stlines" are from two different dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that comes into mind is writing a function that finds outliers based on `upper` and `lower bounds` and then slices the `data frames` based on outliers index e.g.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'wave': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'stlines': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]})

def outlier(value, upper, lower):
    """
    Find outliers based on upper and lower bound
    """
    # Check if input value is within bounds
    in_bounds = (value <= upper) and (value >= lower) 

    return in_bounds 

# Function finds outliers in wave column of DF1
outlier_index = df1.wave.apply(lambda x: outlier(x, 4, 1))

# Return DF2 without values at outlier index
df2[outlier_index]

# Return DF1 without values at outlier index
df1[outlier_index]
```

Comment: This looks cool, but still (technically) slices - I'm wondering what the actual problem is. Perhaps this is too slow or memory hungry...

Comment: I don't see how this solution is slow even for thousands of rows. The OP says that there are 800 rows, which is relatively small sample. (Although, there is probably better way to do it)

Comment: Nor do I - let's see what thre OP says.